# iOS - navigationController pushViewController leaks vc but present does not

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, uikit

When I want to **push** `ProfileViewController` to navigation controller, after **popping** `ProfileViewController`, it leaks and I can see the leaked objects in **MemoryGraph**. each time i open `ProfileViewController` a new object instantiates and will not deallocate.

[image]

*Pushing snippet:*

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

after **popping** the graph of keeping references are:

[image]

**BUT** if I `present` the vc, instead of pushing, the memory leak disappears. so if there was a problem  with keeping strong reference to the vc it should not be different in `presenting`!

**presenting** snippet:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

whats wrong?

Comment: It may be a bug of profiler, but first of all I'd try to find the problem in your code. Try commenting all code in `ProfileViewController`, and any code that's interacting with it in any way, if it still leaks - then probably there's nothing to care about.

Comment: @Philip ok i'll try it and let you know. the problem is with the increasing memory usage in profiler!

Comment: @Philip it's now - class ProfileViewController { //nothing }  - and made sure nothing keeps a refrence to it. even i commented "childCoordinators" and "store" method in my coordinator in case you re familiar with coordinatores.

Comment: still does not deallocate. is it possible that the profiler is showing a bug. i tested on real device either!

Comment: It can be a profile bug for sure. If your view controller is empty and not used anywhere else, that I think it is. But maybe someone else give you an other advice, it's still hard to say without actually seeing the code

Comment: @Mehrdad - too long for a comment, but here's what I would suggest as the next step in your debugging process: https://pastebin.com/c8Pt3sbj ... if you don't see retain / memory leaks, add the `deinit` code to your existing controllers and see if they are being released.

Comment: @DonMag i tested your code. it has no problem and "deinit" calls for both present and push (therfore no leaks on memory graph)

Comment: @Mehrdad - OK... so, it's not an "inherent issue" and it doesn't sound like a "profiler bug." Obviously, your program is much more complex... so it seems *somewhere* your code is holding onto a reference.

Comment: @DonMag as u can see, _UIPageSheetPresentationController is holding the reference which is a private class and i have no idea about it

Comment: @Mehrdad - I was wondering about that, since you say the image is after **popping**. Are you using some sort of custom transition class?

Comment: @DonMag yes it’s after popping. it’s nothing more than swiping right or tapping on back button!

Comment: @Mehrdad - not much left to say other than: do some step-through debugging, use Debug View Hierarchy to try and find out why it appears your controller is being presented when it should be pushed, etc. Can you strip it down to a [mre] ?